# How to get the .apk file of an application programmatically

Tags: android

I want to create an application which has the following functionality. It should save its 
**.apk** file to the **sdcard**. Imagine I have a `Button`. On clicking it I have to save the **.apk** file of the application.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting down-voted. While it's a bit of a weird thing to want to do, it seems a valid question to me. It'd be interesting to hear why you want to do this though.

Comment: Up vote for you , interesting question over here

Comment: Do you mean, you have a list of application which is installed on the device and when you click on it, it should save that application's apk to sdcard.

Comment: Hi aNi , i want exactly that but it would be better if i can implement the above thing also I can do that using this app https://market.android.com/details?id=xcxin.filexpert&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInhjeGluLmZpbGV4cGVydCJd

Comment: If he can do this for an installed app. Why can't we implement the above functionality

Comment: Up vote for you. It is real question with, by the way, great answer! Thank's for both of you.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

It is easy to do that..

1. First you get all installed applications,
2. For each one, get public source directory.
3. copy the file to the SDCard.

Note: No need to be rooted.

Here is the snippt code:

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> apps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo info : apps) {
    File file = new File(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);
    // Copy the .apk file to wherever
}
```

Comment: @Bassel Kh : can you help me how can i copy my apk in my sdcard pls. refer my question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058564/take-backup-of-all-install-apk-file-into-sdcard-programitically-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21058564/take-backup-of-all-install-apk-file-into-sdcard-programitically-in-android).

Comment: Thank you! Works for me.

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't work in Android since that time

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to find and and get all the installed app's apk file through a simple function. Below I wrote a method that return a HashMap Object what holds all the installed apk file's absolute path with their corresponding package name.. I hope it will be very useful to you.

```
private HashMap<String, String> getAllInstalledApkFiles(Context context) {
        HashMap<String, String> installedApkFilePaths = new HashMap<>();

        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packageInfoList = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.SIGNATURE_MATCH);

        if (isValid(packageInfoList)) {
            for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packageInfoList) {
                ApplicationInfo applicationInfo;

                try {
                    applicationInfo = getApplicationInfoFrom(packageManager, packageInfo);

                    String packageName = applicationInfo.packageName;
                    String versionName = packageInfo.versionName;
                    int versionCode = packageInfo.versionCode;

                    File apkFile = new File(applicationInfo.publicSourceDir);
                    if (apkFile.exists()) {
                        installedApkFilePaths.put(packageName, apkFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        LogHelper.d(getClass(), packageName + " = " + apkFile.getName());
                    }
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return installedApkFilePaths;
    }
```

---

```
private boolean isValid(List<PackageInfo> packageInfos) {
        return packageInfos != null && !packageInfos.isEmpty();
    }
```

Now you call the following method to get the apk file for a particular package name :

```
public File getApkFile(Context context, String packageName) {
        HashMap<String, String> installedApkFilePaths = getAllInstalledApkFiles(context);
        File apkFile = new File(installedApkFilePaths.get(packageName));
        if (apkFile.exists()) {
            return apkFile;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and `getApplicationInfoFrom` method:

```
private ApplicationInfo getApplicationInfoFrom(PackageManager packageManager, PackageInfo packageInfo) {
    return packageInfo.applicationInfo;
}
```

Comment: Missing Line of a code ....                                                                 
          private ApplicationInfo getApplicationinfofrom(PackageManager packageManager, PackageInfo packageInfo) {
        return packageInfo.applicationInfo;
    }

Comment: Very useful, I knew there had to be such a thing.  This is what APK extractors do I think, usually have one installed.  I don't have a Java sandbox at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of an official way. However, it seems like the APK is stored in `/data/app` with the filename of `your.package.name-#.apk` where `your.package.name` is your package name (e.g. `com.google.earth`) and `#` is usually 1 or 2, but I imagine it could go up more. Unless your device is rooted, you don't have permissions to list the files in `/data/app` but you should have read access to the actual file. You can try to copy that file (start with 1 and increment until you find it) to the SD card.

Alternatively, if you have internet access, you could store the APK in some web location and download it to SD card directly.

Comment: Kabuko, Firstly thanks a lot for your answer. I have also tried that by using Super One click but i cant implement that. However, i am able to get the .apk of any application including apps from Android Market using the following https://market.android.com/details?id=xcxin.filexpert&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInhjeGluLmZpbGV4cGVydCJd app from market

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **PackageManager and ApplicationInfo** class for this purpose.

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packagelist = new ArrayList<>();
File file;
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
packagelist = packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
if (packagelist.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < packagelist.size(); i++) {
            file = new File(packagelist.get(i).publicSourceDir);
   }
```

This is how you can get the publicSourceDir of every apk. **Then you can just copy that apk in a particular folder.** No ROOT required in this case.

I have created a similar app to extract the apk from both System and Installed apps. It has many more features. Attaching the link of source code and app here . Have a look at them.

[View app on Google PlayStore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.toralabs.apkextractor)

[View Source Code on Github](https://github.com/mrudultora/Apk-Extractor-Android-App)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the simplest way I know on how to get the path to your applications apk file:

```
String classname = "com.mycompany.app.MyActivity";
String apkPath = activity.getApplication().getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(classname, 0).sourceDir
```

classname is the name of your application  Activity or the AppCompatActivity class.

This call would return something like this:

```
/data/app/com.mycompany.app.MyActivity-89lzYNI0vTAV056RT-WHBw==/base.apk
```

You will be able to read the file but you won't be able to write since its protected. And of course, base.apk is a jar.