# java.nio.channels.NonWritableChannelException when try to get backup apk file

Tags: android

I want to get backup installed apk. by using H[ow to get the .apk file of an application programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307034/how-to-get-the-apk-file-of-an-application-programatically) and I get the apk File. and when I try to take backup to another file I get

```
Caused by: java.nio.channels.NonWritableChannelException
```

code to get backup the file:

```
File sourceFile = new File(app.publicSourceDir);
File backupFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "SoundRecorder.apk");
if(!backupFile.exists())
     backupFile.createNewFile();
     if(sourceFile.exists()) {
         FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
         FileChannel dst = new FileInputStream(backupFile).getChannel();
         dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());  <--here I get the exception
         src.close();
         dst.close();
     }
```

I write android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest.xml also.

Comment: You are using a **FileInputStream** as the source your `dst` `FileChannel`. Consider trying a **FileOutputStream** instead, it's more likely to open its channel in write mode..

Comment: @Jens: thank u very much Jens..., u'r really genius... my problem was solved by writting FileOutPutStream to dst.