# Android: backup package data w/o root

Tags: android

I have seen apps which can backup/restore package data from another app without root-ruser permissions. My google-fu seems to be out of wack on this one. How can I do this as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible. I spoke with a developer who I had thought had accomplished this and he said he was only able to do so because the app data in question that he had targeted had relaxed permissions on the data folder.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, I have an app that will backup my user installed apps, It's Astro, and there are others out there that do this as well, w/o root. I'm looking for the way to do this as well....

Comment: Here ya go: [A prettygood answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307034/how-to-get-the-apk-file-of-an-application-programatically)