# Apk file doesn't store in Android SdCard

Tags: android, android-sdcard

These is my AVD:

[image]

In these Command Prompt,I am installed YouTube.apk.That was successfully installed.

[image]

But my problem is it wasn't stored in SdCard.But it is stored in internal memory.

[image]

I need to store that YouTube apk file to my Sdcard. is there any possibilities.Thank You.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307034/how-to-get-the-apk-file-of-an-application-programatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am come up with the answer by following these steps:

1. I created the new AVD by deleting the existing AVD.
2. Then push the apk file by:

   `windows->Open Perspective->DDMS`.

   [image]
3. Finally we need to install these apk with the help of command
   prompt.place your apk file in `android->sdk->platform-tools`

   [image]

   `adb install filename.apk` command used to install the apk file.

   Now,Apk file would be stored in sdcard.That apk file would be installed successfully by command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The location where any application is stored depends on certain setting set during development viz. "android:installLocation" in the Android manifest. You cannot move all apps to the SD Card. Let me know if you need more details on this.

Comment: previously,I moved many files directly to the sdcards.But today I created new avd.But I couldnt move any apk file to sd card.bcoz everything would be stored in internal memory