# Android create apk programmatically

Tags: android, database, apk, programmatically-created, android-multiple-users

I have an app in which i have done some work like updated database with some records. Now i want to generate its .apk file so if i send that .apk to another user he or she can continue work from where i left. Like i wrote a half article, now i want some one else to complete it so i send that .apk to him and he can install it and continue our work. 
All i could find was to get apks for all applications but i want the generated apk to have all the work i done in my app so the other user can continue easily

ref: [How to get the .apk file of an application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307034/how-to-get-the-apk-file-of-an-application-programatically)

Answer (score 1):

You can't send the apk to the other developer, you have to send the source code.  Your best bet is to use an online repository (`github` for example) and share the code that way.

Comment: maybe i wasnt successful in explaining. I have an application for book writing. Now suppose i wrote a chapter. and i have a co writer but he is not with me. now i want him to write the next chapter. So i want to send my app to him . So I want to generate apk of my own app so i can send it to him

Comment: Sorry, this is outside the realm of SO - Telling you how to do something is not the process. You have to write something yourself and then ask for help in debugging. The idea being that you already have something written but it doesn't work.  See [help] for more information.

Comment: I dont know how to start this part. I am in learning phase. Completed my rest of the app but cant figure it out how to generate apk. Please if u can help me it, or if u give me some hint so i go in the right direction :)