# How to get list of all installed Apps in Android and how to take their backup

Tags: android, android-backup-service

i want to make an android app that get list of all installed applications and after that user may select various apps and save their backups on google drive

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8743332/3981656

Answer (score 0):

This can help you to get all installed apps,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> apps = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent , 0);
```

Comment: works great! this is the first part of my question, now can you please tell me that how i can take backups of various apps that the user has selected?

Comment: First try to find out how apk files are store in sd card and then try this [tutorial](https://www.numetriclabz.com/integrate-google-drive-in-android-tutorial/)